# Redirect user after authentication? Replace is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to have the user authenticated before my react app displays the home page. Most tutorials show a "replace" from within react-router. For some reason I keep getting errors stating that replace is not a function.

**Here is my code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    async isLoggedIn() {
        const user = await axios.get('/api/currentUser');

        if(user.data === "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
        (async () => {
            const data = await this.isLoggedIn();

            if(!data) {
                replace({
                    pathname: "/api/login"
                });
            }
        })();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route path="/" component={Home} onEnter={this.requireAuth()} exact/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Am I not importing correctly? I couldn't find anything with an explanation.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `this.requireAuth()`, but the actual method expects two arguments to be passed to it `requireAuth(nextState, replace)`.  So  then, when you try to call `replace()` you get an error because it's `undefined`.

Comment: replace is a callback function it looks like, so you will have to define it, or it looks like a possible solution could be to change `onEnter={this.requireAuth()}` to `onEnter={this.requireAuth}` which **may** allow React-Router to pass in `replace()` using closure.

Comment: But to make sure we get some good data here. I agree with jfriend00. Your problem is `requireAuth(nextState, replace) {` does not match `this.requireAuth()`. You need to call it like `this.requireAuth(nextState, replace)`. I think it's worth trying to just remove the `()` first (as I showed in my previous comment). If that works, someone can expand on why.

Comment: try this `onEnter={this.requireAuth}` first

Comment: Btw what version of react-router-dom are you using. Seems onEnter is removed in 4.0.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should change `onEnter={this.requireAuth()}` to `onEnter={this.requireAuth}`

Based on the following documentation, `onEnter` accept a function as parameter and will be injected for `nextState, replace, callback?` parameters. The full signature of this function will be `onEnter(nextState, replace, callback?)`.

**Detailed description**

> onEnter(nextState, replace, callback?) Called when a route is about to
>   be entered. It provides the next router state and a function to
>   redirect to another path. this will be the route instance that
>   triggered the hook.
>
> If callback is listed as a 3rd argument, this hook will run
>   asynchronously, and the transition will block until callback is
>   called.

**Sample Code**

```
const userIsInATeam = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
  fetch(...)
    .then(response = response.json())
    .then(userTeams => {
      if (userTeams.length === 0) {
        replace(`/users/${nextState.params.userId}/teams/new`)
      }
      callback();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // do some error handling here
      callback(error);
    })
}

<Route path="/users/:userId/teams" onEnter={userIsInATeam} />
```

Hope it helps